# Semilogx plot issues

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

Quite simply, both plots are semilogx, although the range of x values isn't 10^0, 10^1, etc, as is on the bottom plot (which is what I desire), and the grid isn't what I am looking for. I need to be able to see the x intercept, which is why I need the x axis to look like that of the bottom graph but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

this is the desired graph, but I don't know how to achieve it in matlab. It's been a very long time since I've used this software

[image]
Here is the code for starters...

```
Exposure = [53.19, 79.79, 132.98, 212.77, 455.93];
Cure_depth = [10.88, 14.56, 19.19, 23.45, 30.36];
semilogx(Exposure,Cure_depth, '-*')
grid on
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [stairs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) function with *XSale* set to *log*.

Example:

```
figure;
ax = gca;
stairs(ax, Exposure, Cure_depth, '-');
set(ax, 'XScale', 'log');
grid(ax, 'on');
hold(ax, 'on');
plot(ax, Exposure, Cure_depth, '-*');
xlabel(ax, 'Exposure (mJ/cm^2)');
title(ax, 'Cure Depth vs. Exposure');
ylabel(ax, 'Cure Depth (mils)');
```

[image]